# Laravel Livewire Validation - required_without_all and required_without dont work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire component:

```
  class Cards extends Component
  {
   use WithFileUploads;

   public $question;
   public $answer;

   public $questionImage;
   public $questionImageOrigin;
   public $answerImage;
   public $answerImageOrigin;

   public $questionAudio;
   public $questionAudioOrigin;
   public $answerAudio;
   public $answerAudioOrigin;

   public function render()
   {
       return view('livewire.cards');
   }
```

Now I want to create and validate a card:

```
   public function createCard()
{
    $this->validate([
        'answerImage' => 'nullable|image|max:3000',
        'questionImage' => 'nullable|image|max:3000',
        'question' => 'required_without_all: questionImage, questionAudio',
        'answer' => 'required_without: answerImage, answerAudio',
        'questionAudio' => 'nullable|file|mimeTypes:audio/mpeg|max:3000',
        'answerAudio' => 'nullable|file|mimeTypes:audio/mpeg|max:3000'
    ]);
```

But this is not working.
When I insert something (image or audio) I get the error:

```
The answer field is required when answer image / answer audio is not present.
```

So - I guess this is not working. Or am I wrong?
Maybe I have to use another syntax?
But I found nothing in the docs.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added space in the rule

```
'answer' => 'required_without: answerImage, answerAudio',
```

Change it to this

```
'answer' => 'required_without:answerImage,answerAudio',
```

And

```
'question' => 'required_without_all: questionImage, questionAudio',
```

to this

```
'question' => 'required_without_all:questionImage,questionAudio',
```

Comment: Yes - that was it. Thanks very much.